# How do I combine currentMinute and currentHour into one single time value which can be displayed in an XML file?

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite, timepicker

So I'd like to display the currentMinute and currentHour variables I've defined via a TimePicker in my layout add_country.xml - I thought I'd coded everything correctly but I can't seem to display the new variable I've created with the two combined time values @+id/normalTimeFormat located in view_country's:

```
<TableRow>       
  <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="Time Limit"/>                    
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/normalTimeFormat"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow>
```

## view_country.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="1" 
android:layout_margin="5dp">
<TableRow>         
  <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="@string/time_lbl"/>
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/timeText" 
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>
<TableRow>         
  <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="@string/name_lbl"/>
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/nameText" 
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>

 <TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="@string/cap_lbl"/>         
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/capText"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>

  <TableRow>       
  <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="Time Limit"/>                    
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/codeText"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow>       
  <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="Time Limit"/>                    
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/normalTimeFormat"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="Linked Users"/>         
 <TextView 
android:id="@+id/codeText"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="@string/code_lbl"/>         
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>  

</TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

## ViewCoreDevice.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class ViewCoreDevice extends Activity {

       private long rowID;
       private TextView nameTv;
       private TextView capTv;
       private TextView codeTv; 
       private TextView timeTv; 
       private TextView minTv; 

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.view_country);

          setUpViews();
          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
          rowID = extras.getLong(CoreDeviceList.ROW_ID); 
       }

       private void setUpViews() {
           nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
           capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
           timeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
           minTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
           codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onResume()
       {
          super.onResume();
          new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
       } 

       private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
       {
          DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCoreDevice.this);

          @Override
          protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
          {
             dbConnector.open();
             return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
          } 

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
          {
             super.onPostExecute(result);

             result.moveToFirst();
             // get the column index for each data item
             int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
             int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
             int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");
             int timeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("time");

             nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
             capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
//           timeTv.setText(result.getInt(timeIndex)); // <--- HERE WAS AN ERROR
             timeTv.setText(result.getString(timeIndex)); // time was stored as Sting all the time
             minTv.setText(result.getString(timeIndex));
             codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));

             result.close();
             dbConnector.close();
          }
       } 


       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
       {
          super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
          return true;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
       {
          switch (item.getItemId())
          {
             case R.id.editItem:
                Intent addEditContact =
                   new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

                addEditContact.putExtra(CoreDeviceList.ROW_ID, rowID);
                addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
                addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
                addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
                startActivity(addEditContact); 
                return true;

             case R.id.deleteItem:
                deleteContact();
                return true;

             default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          } 
       }

       private void deleteContact()
       {

          AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCoreDevice.this);

          alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
          alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

          alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
             {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
                {
                   final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                      new DatabaseConnector(ViewCoreDevice.this);

                   AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                      new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                      {
                         @Override
                         protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                         {
                            dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                            return null;
                         } 

                         @Override
                         protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                         {
                            finish(); 
                         }
                      };

                   deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
                }
             }
          );

          alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
       }
    }
```

## AddEditCountry.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;


public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

     private long rowID; 
     private EditText nameEt;
     private EditText capEt;
     private EditText codeEt;
     private TimePicker timeEt;
     private TimePicker minEt;
     private String cHour;
     private String cMinute;
     private String normalTimeFormat;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

          nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
          capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
          codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
          timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
          minEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);



          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

          if (extras != null)
          {
             rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
             nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
             capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
             codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));  
             timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.getInt("time"));
             minEt.setCurrentMinute(extras.getInt("min"));
          }

          Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
          saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                 if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
                 {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                       new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                       {
                          @Override
                          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                          {
                             saveContact();
                             return null;
                          }

                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                          {
                             finish();
                          }
                       }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                 }

                 else
                 {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                    alert.show();
                 }
              } 
         });
       }


           private void saveContact() 
           {
              DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

              if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
              {
                  dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),
                          timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                          minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                          codeEt.getText().toString());
              }
              else
              {
                  dbConnector.updateContact(rowID, nameEt.getText().toString(),capEt.getText().toString(),timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString()+":"+minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(), codeEt.getText().toString());
                    }
           }
}
```

## add_country.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">

   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:padding="5dp">

      <EditText android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
         android:hint="@string/name_hint"
         android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

      <EditText android:id="@+id/capEdit"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
         android:hint="@string/cap_hint"
         android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data Limit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="10MB" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Unlimited Data" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bandwidth Limit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="10kbs" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Unlimited Bandwidth" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WiFi Time Limit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/codeEdit"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:lines="1"
        android:hint="@string/code_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext" />




      <Button android:id="@+id/saveBtn" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:text="@string/save_btn"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579715/how-can-i-combine-the-currentminute-and-currenthour-into-one-text-field-so-it-di ?

Comment: Still need help - the issue changed a bit - figured I'd make a new post and clear things up w my latest source code since we made so many changes from the way I originally posted it before

Comment: This post is way too long for us to try to figure out why your value is not displayed in your UI. Make a small example that demonstrates your problem with no extraneous code, such as database or additional Activities. 9 times out of 10 the exercise of consolidating your problem will reveal the solution to you. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should use something that return current time, like `new Date()` or `Calendar.getInstance()` combined with `SimpleDateFormat.format(Date)`. Something like this

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:m");
Date date = new Date();
format.format(date);
```

You can choose the right format for you.

Comment: I don't need to return the current time... I need to return the time from the TimePicker I have implemented above.

Comment: But in AddEditCountry.java you have a `String` variable `normalTimeFormat` and `id/normalTimeFormat` is not initialized, am I right?
Was not enough 
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
TextView normal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.normalTimeFormat);
normal.setText(timePicker.getCurrentHour() + ":" + timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
??
If is it right, let me know, to edit/create another answer

Comment: I updated my AddEditCountry - I've created a combined variable - I'm just trying to resolve the issue where I get the error:

"The method updateContact(long, String, String, String, String, String) in the type DatabaseConnector is not applicable for the arguments" 

when cleaning AddEditCountry (as shown/updated in the post above)

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can assign the two values I get from TimePicker (currentHour and currentMinute [of the TimePicker]) to a single variable?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it at this way.

**First, i would change your field's type "time" on your database. String -> long**

- Change your SQL
- Change your CRUD methods

At insertion moment, you would use System.currentTimeMillis to store it on database.

So when you would get the information of your database, you will get a long. At this time, you need just convert for a format better for you.

At this point you can do as @Moesio said:

```
       SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:m");
       Date date = new Date();
       timeTv.setText(format.format(date).toString());
```